# Message from debugger: unable to attach error for osx app

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I have been building mac app on my mac mini and it always worked well but today i faced this error, searched a lot but no luck.

**Message from debugger: unable to attach**

What i tried:

- Clear derived data
- Quit Xcode
- Restart machine
- installation directory set to blank and also to /Applications
- Tried Skip Install No / Yes
- Using developer Signing certs
- M using only Developer certificates and not provisioning profile to sign my cocoa app

**Xcode 8.2**

**OSX 10.12.1**

Please help :)

Comment: y a downvote? i have searched stack overflow already and didnt found a solution... so posted a question, for a downvote provide a reason or solution

Comment: Found the solution : Framework was not loaded, no error was shown by xcode.. phew...

Comment: Mine is terminated with sigkill 9. It seems impossible to find a solution.

Comment: `Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme... -> Run -> Info -> Launch` = `Automatically`.

Answer (score 4):

This is what fixed it for me, perhaps it will help others but I do realize the question was for 8.2. I had it set to Xcode 9 "New Build System" disabling this and switching to "Standard Build System" in the Project Settings under the File Menu. I had tried all the other things like killing DerivedData, clean build, restarting Xcode. I also verified that my dependent libraries were set correctly. The only thing that worked was disabling new "New Build System"

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem today. I have little demo code in a mac project(created with `Xcode 9.4`). This error just started to occur after I upgraded system to `macOS Mojave 10.14`. However, in `Xcode 10` this project runs no problem(without changing anything). If you can use Xcode 10 it will probably be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the above solutions didn't work for me (although I am sure they work for some people).

Here is what worked for me, in case this helps anyone else:

- Close Xcode
- Open Xcode and `Create a new Xcode project`
- In the *iOS* template, select `Single View App` then click *Next*

  - yes, I know you are trying to get a macOS app attaching to the debugger :).
- Give the iOS app any *product name* and *organization identifier* you would like and click *Next*
- *Create* the new project anywhere you would like (I saved it to my desktop)
- Build and run (`cmd + r`) the iOS app on a simulator like the iPhone 8 (starting a simulator and running the iOS app will take a little time, so have patients)
- After the iOS app runs in the simulator, click to stop it from running (the stop button is next to the run button)
- Open your macOS app that you are having trouble connecting a debugger to, and build and run it (`cmd + r`)

This, for some reason, allowed me to connect to the debugger with my macOS app...

**Xcode version: 10.1**, **macOS Mojave version: 10.14.2**

Comment: I was seeing this for the XCUITests associated with my Mac app.  I deleted the test target, and re-added, and the first time around I got challenges for an Accessibility helper for Xcode.  Once I enabled the helper in System Prefs, I was able to see the console for the UI tests.